# How to style/aligh xp:pager control?

Tags: css, xpages, lotus-notes

How to align left DataTable xp:pager control?
Header and Footer pagers appear only on right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to override the xspPagerRight class in your stylesheet like so

```
.xspPagerRight{float:left}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you disable the theme it will be left aligned

```
<xp:pager xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" disableTheme="true"></xp:pager>
```

or you can you can add the outerStyleClass xspPagerLeft to your pager

```
<xp:pager xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" outerStyleClass="xspPagerLeft"></xp:pager>
```

or you can add the styleClass xspPagerLeft to your pager

```
<xp:pager xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" styleClass="xspPagerLeft"></xp:pager>
```